# change markerSnippet at google maps on android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, google-maps-markers

I have an activity called `GatherActivity` where I have an `EditText`. The user can input what ever he wants. Now I need the input of that `EditText` in a different class, called `MapActivity`.
I created an `Intent` to "put it over" in the other activity. But it doesn't work like I aspect it. the object/editText is allways a null object, so nothing is displayed as a markerSnippet.
Here my Code (GahterActivity) in a method onButtonClick():

```
public void onButtonClick(View view){

EditText editText_markerSnippet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_markerSnippet);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("markerSnippet", editText_markerSnippet.getText().toString());
}
```

Code in MapActivity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        markerSnippet = extras.getParcelable("markerSnippet");
}else{
    markerSnippet = "some extra info about your location"
}
```

in my marker snippet there is no text. so the else case is not in use here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a `String`, but expecting a `Parcelable` in your activity.

In your `MapActivity`, change it to:

```
markerSnippet = extras.getString("markerSnippet");
```

Comment: that worked,thanks,. for other guys: remember to start next activity with
`startActivity(intent);`